# jQuery Combine Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have two similar functions that I would like to combine so that I can use anywhere throughout the site. It's a simple jquery slideUp / slideDown effect that finds the div with the class 'hidden' and on click, it shows and hides

```
$('.clicker1').click(function(){

    // grab the hidden content
    var desc = $(this).parent().find('.hidden');

    // remove toggle class and slide up
    if ($(this).hasClass('toggled')) {
       $(this).removeClass('toggled');
       $(desc).slideUp(400, 'linear');  
    }

    // add toggle class, slide down, and move the page up
    else {
       var loc = this;

      $(desc).slideDown(400, 'linear', function () {
        $.scrollTo($(loc).offset().top - 60, 400);
      });

      $(this).addClass('toggled');
      $('.clicker1').not(this).removeClass('toggled');
      $('.hidden').not(desc).slideUp(400, 'linear');    
    }
  });

$('.clicker2').click(function(){

    // grab the hidden content
    var desc = $(this).parent().find('.hidden2');

    // remove toggle class and slide up
    if ($(this).hasClass('toggled')) {
       $(this).removeClass('toggled');
       $(desc).slideUp(400, 'linear');  
    }

    // add toggle class, slide down, and move the page up
    else {
       var loc = this;

      $(desc).slideDown(400, 'linear', function () {
        $.scrollTo($(loc).offset().top - 60, 400);
      });

      $(this).addClass('toggled');
      $('.clicker2').not(this).removeClass('toggled');
      $('.hidden').not(desc).slideUp(400, 'linear');    
    }
  });
```

Can I create one function and put in my own 'clickerX' and 'hiddenX' ?

Comment: Have you thought of using the jQuery toggle http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the handlers only differ by the class's they use as selectors.  The easiest approach is to write a function which generates a click handler based on the class names.  Try the following

```
var makeHandler = function(className, hiddenClassName, ) {

  return function() {
    // grab the hidden content
    var desc = $(this).parent().find(hiddenClassName);

    // remove toggle class and slide up
    if ($(this).hasClass('toggled')) {
       $(this).removeClass('toggled');
       $(desc).slideUp(400, 'linear');  
    }

    // add toggle class, slide down, and move the page up
    else {
       var loc = this;

      $(desc).slideDown(400, 'linear', function () {
        $.scrollTo($(loc).offset().top - 60, 400);
      });

      $(this).addClass('toggled');
      $(className).not(this).removeClass('toggled');
      $(hiddenClassName).not(desc).slideUp(400, 'linear');    
  };
};


$('.clicker1').click(makeHandler('.clicker1', '.hidden'));
$('.clicker2').click(makeHandler('.clicker2', '.hidden2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You want to write a plugin. There's tons of tutorials on making a jQuery plugin, but the [official docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) give a good start.

Comment: That is a comment, not an answer. You sound like you're saying, "We won't help you, RTFM," and expecting to get points for it.

Comment: The question was "Can I create one function and put in my own 'clickerX' and 'hiddenX' ?" The proper way to do this with jQuery is  to write a plugin. How is this not an answer? Was I supposed to write the code for him?

Comment: I have to agree with Craig. While examples are nice, he does answer User's question. He also provides a link to the docs to get the guy started. How is that not an answer? Sometimes redundant code examples aren't as helpful as the documentation of the product. Where there are tons of examples I might add.

Comment: Answers should be constructive, should show some creative effort, and should show an actual attempt to understand the problem. Craig's response did none of those things. More importantly, his tone came across (to me) as unhelpful and dismissive. However, he clearly does not make a habit of such answers, for which I am appreciative.